# JQuery Dialog title not following mousemove

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-ui, dialog

I'm tying to have different popup boxes show when the cursor is on certain sections of an image using hotspots/image maps. I had everything working well based on [this previously answered question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20969780/show-hide-jquery-dialog-box-on-mouseover). However, when I attempted to change the locations where the dialog box pops up from the center of the window to following the cursor, the text of the dialog box moves while the title and header/content box itself remains centered.

I've tried changing the position designations in the jquery.ui css, changing the ".box" to other classes, and did manage to move the title box using:

```
$(this).dialog({modal:false, resizable:false,autoOpen:false, position:"left"});
```

or other position variations there, but it is still not following the cursor.

What's going wrong?

```js
$(function() {

  $('.box').each(function(k, v) {
    var box =
      $(this).dialog({
        modal: false,
        resizable: false,
        autoOpen: false,
      });
    $(this).parent().find('.ui-dialog-titlebar-close').hide();

    $("#elem" + k)
      .mouseover(function() {
        box.dialog("open");
      })
      .mouseout(function() {
        box.dialog("close");
      })
      .mousemove(function() {
        box.position({
          my: "left+3 bottom-3",
          of: event
        });
      })

  });

});
```

```html
<link href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<section class="legacy">
  <h3>background</h3>
  <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/433539/pexels-photo-433539.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=750&w=1260" alt="background" usemap="#image" id="background" />
  <map name="image">

      <area shape="poly" coords="580,637,673,667,661,768,631,773,594,791,558,813,542,838,526,810,493,789,464,787,433,801,432,784,459,726,491,681,536,653" alt="Landsat 1" class="element" id="elem0">
   <area shape="poly" coords="703,608,725,438,759,292,802,214,846,176,893,204,918,265,937,347,947,436,927,504,786,611,721,626" alt="Landsat 2" class="element" id="elem1">
   <area shape="poly" coords="395,793,336,692,242,669,135,657,94,683,80,718,110,759,180,778,263,797" alt="Landsat 3" class="element" id="elem2">
 </map>
  <div id="box0" class="box" title="test 1">popup 1 c</div>
  <div id="box1" class="box" title="test 2">popup2.</div>
  <div id="box2" class="box" title="test 3">popup3</div>

</section>
```

[View on JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ecrisp/djvpfuws/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you need to call `dialog()` to set the position.
See [dialog() position](https://api.jqueryui.com/dialog/#option-position).

I assume `dialog()` returns a jQuery object of the original element, for [chaining](http://www.jquerybyexample.net/2012/06/what-is-chaining-in-jquery.html).
That original element ends up becoming the content area of the dialog, excluding the titlebar etc.
That's why only the content area is moving and not the box outline or titlebar.

So, in your `mousemove` handler, instead of this:

```
box.position({
  my: "left+3 bottom-3",
  of: event
});
```

Use this:

```
box.dialog({
  position: {
    my: "left+3 bottom-3",
    of: event
  }
});
```

Or this:

```
box.dialog("option","position",{
  my: "left+3 bottom-3",
  of: event
});
```

(Below, I've used CSS to scale the image down for demonstration purposes.)

```js
$(function() {
  $('.box').each(function(k, v) {
  
    var box =
      $(this).dialog({
        modal: false,
        resizable: false,
        autoOpen: false,
      });
    $(this).parent().find('.ui-dialog-titlebar-close').hide();

    $("#elem" + k)
      .mouseover(function() {
        box.dialog("open");
      })
      .mouseout(function() {
        box.dialog("close");
      })
      .mousemove(function() {
        box.dialog({
          position: {
            my: "left+3 bottom-3",
            of: event
          }
        });
      });

  });
});
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.legacy {
  transform-origin: top left;
  transform: scale(0.15);
}
```

```html
<link href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>


<section class="legacy">

  <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/433539/pexels-photo-433539.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=750&w=1260" alt="background" usemap="#image" id="background" />

  <map name="image">
    <area shape="poly" coords="580,637,673,667,661,768,631,773,594,791,558,813,542,838,526,810,493,789,464,787,433,801,432,784,459,726,491,681,536,653" alt="Landsat 1" class="element" id="elem0">
    <area shape="poly" coords="703,608,725,438,759,292,802,214,846,176,893,204,918,265,937,347,947,436,927,504,786,611,721,626" alt="Landsat 2" class="element" id="elem1">
    <area shape="poly" coords="395,793,336,692,242,669,135,657,94,683,80,718,110,759,180,778,263,797" alt="Landsat 3" class="element" id="elem2">
  </map>

  <div id="box0" class="box" title="test 1">popup 1 c</div>
  <div id="box1" class="box" title="test 2">popup2.</div>
  <div id="box2" class="box" title="test 3">popup3</div>

</section>
```

Comment: you are a lifesaver. I tried variations of adding .dialog back in previously, but I'm a complete novice so I must not have been using it quite correctly. Thanks so much!